# MiniTest Error: "NameError: uninitialized constant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, minitest, nameerror

I'm following Michael Hartl's "Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Web Development", and creating the tests that check a user's name and email for validity of length (name as a maximum of 50 chars, email as 255 chars). The contents of `test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb` are:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "full_title_helper" do
    assert_equal full_title,         FILL_IN
    assert_equal full_title("Help"), FILL_IN
  end
end
```

---

Upon running `bundle exec rake test`, all tests pass, but I see the following message flagged as an error at the end:

```
ERROR["test_full_title_helper", ApplicationHelperTest, 1.820016791]
test_full_title_helper#ApplicationHelperTest (1.82s)
NameError:         NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationHelperTest::FILL_IN
        test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ApplicationHelperTest>'
    test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ApplicationHelperTest>'
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'd imagine `FILL_IN` is meant to be filled in as some kind of exercise or something, not used literally.

Comment: Exactly. If you read the error message carefully, Ruby tells you that it does not know what `FILL_IN` is. Read the exercise description https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-layout_exercises

Comment: You guys are absolutely right, that was the issue. I replaced FILL_IN with "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" and "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" which solved the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the issue is FILL_IN isn't the literal title (obviously), so it needs to be replaced with "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App", and "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" respectively. -Thanks to Nick Veys and p11y for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The FILL_IN constants can be replaced by :name, :email

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
#...
has_many :microposts
validates :name, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true
#...
```